# Postfix Log - Get entries for certain mail only

Tags: postfix, logging

The standard Postfix log Format is something like

`Feb 4 15:03:53 mail postfix/smtp[31148]: xyz`

The 31148 seems to be the process id, so this does not necessarily change if I send another mail. At least in my logs, I got output lines for far more than one mail with that id.

How can I have log lines to be mapped for each single message sent? Thank you!

P.S.: I've seen there a snippets of Postfix logs with a message or queue Id after the process id, but I could not find a way to to print that in the debian 9.5 standard postfix install.

Answer (score 1):

What you have here is a standard syslog prefix containing the time, hostname, process name and process id in square brackets. What you present shortly as `xyz` is the actual log message from Postfix. **For queued messages the log message from Postfix starts with a message ID.**

The message ID is unique to a message and can be used for searching all log lines related to the delivery of the message (except for `connect`, `disconnect` & TLS connection details). Additionally, e.g., OpenDKIM & OpenDMARC prefixes the messages with the same ID, so you can find them from the same mail logs, too.

An example with the standard syslog prefix shortened using `awk` &  `tr`:

```
$ grep 123456789A /var/log/mail.log | awk '{$1=$2=""; print $0}' | tr -d ' '
postfix/smtpd[136943]: 123456789A: client=mail.example.com[198.51.100.5]
postfix/cleanup[136949]: 123456789A: message-id=<abbaacdc-abba-acdc-abba-acdcabbaacdc@mail.example.com>
opendkim[785]: 123456789A: mail.example.com [198.51.100.5] not internal
opendkim[785]: 123456789A: not authenticated
opendkim[785]: 123456789A: message has signatures from example.com, example.com
opendkim[785]: 123456789A: signature=JkaxE6J1 domain=example.com selector=s1 result="no signature error"; signature=Ra0RqB6n domain=example.com selector=s2 result="no signature error"
opendkim[785]: 123456789A: DKIM verification successful
opendkim[785]: 123456789A: s=s1 d=example.com a=rsa-sha256 SSL 
opendmarc[815]: 123456789A: SPF(mailfrom): mail.example.com pass
opendmarc[815]: 123456789A: mail.example.com pass
postfix/qmgr[127294]: 123456789A: from=<user@example.com>, size=3527, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
postfix/local[136950]: 123456789A: to=<user@mail.example.net>, orig_to=<alias@example.net>, relay=local, delay=17, delays=2.4/0.01/0/15, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to command: procmail -a "$EXTENSION")
postfix/qmgr[127294]: 123456789A: removed
```

Comment: Thank for your help! That's indeed what I found out in P.S. part of the question, but I couldn't get it to work with postfix 3.1.8. It just logs without the message/queue-ID ("xyz" in my example doenst contain such an ID). It's an Debian 9.5 which cannot be updatet that easy. Although I couldn't find any useful documentation how to configure output except inreasing debug level (which there seems also to be no detailied information). By increasing loglevel it prints out the queueID but not for all lines of a messages log, especially not in the TLS detail part. Any help is still apreciated!

Comment: I need the TLS part or an information regarding messageId to have used encryption.

Comment: I'm afraid using an EoL version of Debian would make your question off-topic on Serverfault, whereas any current version works as explained in this answer. The lines containing TLS information could be found using the hostname, but not the message ID.

Comment: Thank you again. But since you already pointed out "except for connect, disconnect & TLS connection details" this isn't possible in current versions also and hostnames are not unqiue in a logfile. So do I get that right, that you also see no simple and clean way to map TLS details to a certain message in the log?